# How to see all "ancestors" of a recursive data model?

Tags: ios, json, swift, algorithm, recursive-datastructures

I am receiving a JSON:

```
{
    "categories":
    [
        {
            "category_name": "example name",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "category_name": "example name"
                },
                {
             ...
```

As can be seen, the data is a recursive format. I was able to write the code for decoding it into my custom type which is:

```
 struct Name: Codable {
        let cat: String
        let children: [cat]?
}
```

Now, for any cat, I would like to know the "path" of it. As in, I'd like know what are all the super(ancestor) categories. So, for the category "tablets", I would like to be able to traverse what the drill down structure looks like, which in this case could look like:

```
Electronics -> Computers -> Laptops and Tablets -> Tablets
```

How do I structure my code or data model to be able to retrieve this information for any category?

Comment: You did not show a json with the example you give at the end. BTW, for your need, you should create  add optional category field in category struct that you can fill after json decoding.

Comment: The bottom example is just an example of categories within a category within a category as represented in the json above. Sorry if I wasn’t clear.

Comment: No problem. What can also be done is to use classes instead of structs so when going backwards you go to the parent category, not only it’s name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll want to add the path to Category so you have somewhere to store the data. For convenience, I'll also add a CategoriesResponse just to handle the top-level structure, but it's not really important:

```
struct CategoriesResponse: Decodable {
    var categories: [Category]
}

struct Category {
    let path: [String]
    let categoryName: String
    let children: [Category]
}
```

(I'm assuming what you want are just the names of the parent categories. If you want references of some kind, that's possible, but the data structures get a little more complicated. This basic approach will still work, though. Let me know if you need something like that, and I can expand the answer.)

And of course standard CodingKeys stuff:

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case categoryName = "category_name"
    case children
}
```

The meat of the solution is that you need an init that can accept a KeyedDecodingContainer (rather than a Decoder) and a path, and handle decoding everything else.

```
// For each element, decode out of the container by hand rather than recursing into init(from: Decoder)
private init(from container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>, path: [String]) throws {
    // Track our own path up to this point
    self.path = path

    // Unload the usual stuff
    self.categoryName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .categoryName)

    // Construct the children, one element at a time (if children exists)
    var children: [Category] = []

    if container.contains(.children) {
        // Extract the array of children
        var childrenContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .children)
        while !childrenContainer.isAtEnd {
            // Extract the child object
            let childContainer = try childrenContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

            // For each child, extend the path, decode
            let child = try Category(from: childContainer, path: path + [self.categoryName])

            // And append
            children.append(child)
        }
    }
    self.children = children
}
```

And finally, you need a Decodable implementation just to kick it all off:

```
extension Category: Decodable {
    // Top level decoder to kick everything off
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try self.init(from: container, path: [])
    }
}
```

With that, it should work as expected using a standard Decoder:

```
let categories = try JSONDecoder().decode(CategoriesResponse.self, from: json).categories
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for such elegant solution. I wish I could find an article explaining in detail what you did here.  :)

Comment: I'm considering adding this example to my Codable talk that I'l be presenting at [360iDev](https://360idev.com/speaker/rob-napier/). Great conference if you're looking for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic recursive solution that adds the path of elements to an array with the root element as the first and the targeted element as the last.

It uses `contains()` so `Category` needs to conform to `Equatable` or it could be changed to use `contains(where:) instead like

```
contains(where: { $0.categoryName == target.categoryName })
```

if it is a more practical solution.

```
func extractChain(for target: Category, parent: Category, chain: inout [Category]) {
    guard let children = parent.children else {
        chain = []
        return
    }

    chain.append(parent)

    if children.contains(target) {
        chain.append(target)
        return
    }

    for category in children where category.children != nil {
        extractChain(for: target, parent: category, chain: &chain)
        if !chain.isEmpty { return }
    }
    chain = [] // No match, clear the array
}
```

I've only made some basic tests, one with a match the 3rd level down and one with no match so some further testing is probably needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class and ancestor like this :

```
class Category: Codable {
    let category_name: String
    let children: [Category]?
    var ancestor : Category?

    func setupAncestor(ancestor: Category?) {
        self.ancestor = ancestor
        if let children = children {
            for child in children {
                child.setupAncestor(ancestor: self)
            }
        }
    }

    func ancestors() -> [Category] {
        if let ancestor = ancestor {
            var ancestorList = [ancestor]
              ancestorList.append(contentsOf: ancestor.ancestors())
             return ancestorList
        }
        return []
    }
    
    func ancestorsNames() -> [String] {
        if let ancestor = ancestor {
            var ancestorList = [ancestor.category_name]
              ancestorList.append(contentsOf: ancestor.ancestorsNames())
             return ancestorList
        }
        return []
    }
    
    func displayAncestors() {
        for ancestor in ancestors() {
            print("Ancestor : \(ancestor.category_name)")
        }
    }
    func display(_ level: Int) {
        print("Level \(level)")
        print("Category : \(category_name) \(ancestorsNames())")
        //displayAncestors()
        if let children = children {
            for child in children {
                child.display(level+1)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Categories : Codable {
    let categories: [Category]
    func setupAncestors() {
        for category in categories {
            category.setupAncestor(ancestor: nil)
        }
    }
}

let json = "..."
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let categories = try decoder.decode(Categories.self, from: jsonData!)
    categories.setupAncestors()
    for category in categories.categories {
        category.display(0)
    }
    
} catch {
    print("Json decode error : \(error)")
}
```

You can change the order and/or return only categoryName in the list

EDIT : corrected the code

Comment: In `setupAncestors` you have `category.ancestor`, what is that ? Or did you mean `parentCategory. ancestor` ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank , my mistake, I meant ancestor. I corrected the answer.

Comment: `setupAncestor(ancestor: self, forCategory: child)`, this function isn't included or did you mean `child.setupAncestor(ancestor: self)`? And does the function `ancestors()` really compile?